# identifierForVendor returns the same identifier even if I removed all the applications for the same vendors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, udid, uidevice

I'm experimenting a little with the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) API.

As per the doc

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. **The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.** Therefore, if
>   your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should
>   gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

In Debug or Release with Ad Hoc, I cannot replicate this behavior. The identifier still remains the same even if I remove all the applications I have installed for the same vendor (the reversed domain name I'm using, e.g. `com.test`).

Is this can be observed only for App Store distribution? Am I missing something?

I'm running on a iOS 8.3.

Related question: [iOS7 - Device unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013245/ios7-device-unique-identifier).

Comment: Maybe it is essential that you cannot rely on fact that this will remain same but the situations when it exactly changes not documented well?

Comment: @Azat I think so. I will give a feedback in the documentation to point out this. Anyway, I'm curious to know if the behavior can be replicated on App Store applications. Thanks for the typo fix :-)

Comment: When I tested this behavior, I just logged vendorID in AppDelegate - after reinstallation of the app there is a new vendorID. Maybe, it is possible that after every install you have the same value, but maybe you just have another app with the same bundle? Test app or smth like that?